# Hide popper of one field when opening popper of another field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am implementing two text fields next to each other and they have end adornments as a buttons. Those buttons toggle popper visibility. Also each popper has clickawaylistener so the popper is closed when mouse clicks outside popper. If first popper is opened it should be closed when I click button of second text field adornment. Issue is that end adornments have event propagation stopped. I do that to prevent clickaway event when clicking adornment, so to prevent instant closing of popper when it is opened by toggle handler.

I was thinking about wrapping TextField into ClickAwayListener but it didn't work.

P.S. Both TextField will be rendered from separate components and I don't want to share any props between them as they should be independent.

https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-forked-rykrx

```
  const [firstPopperVisible, setFirstPopperVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const [secondPopperVisible, setSecondPopperVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const firstTextFieldRef = React.useRef();
  const secondTextFieldRef = React.useRef();

  const toggleFirstPopperVisible = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setFirstPopperVisible((prev) => !prev);
  };
  const handleFirstPopperClickAway = (e) => {
    setFirstPopperVisible(false);
  };
  const toggleSecondPopperVisible = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setSecondPopperVisible((prev) => !prev);
  };
  const handleSecondPoppertClickAway = (e) => {
    setSecondPopperVisible(false);
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <div>
        <TextField
          label="Outlined"
          variant="outlined"
          inputRef={firstTextFieldRef}
          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                  edge="end"
                  onClick={toggleFirstPopperVisible}
                >
                  <Visibility />
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }}
        />
        <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleFirstPopperClickAway}>
          <Popper
            open={firstPopperVisible}
            anchorEl={firstTextFieldRef.current}
            placement="bottom-start"
          >
            Content
          </Popper>
        </ClickAwayListener>
      </div>
      <div>
        <TextField
          label="Outlined"
          variant="outlined"
          inputRef={secondTextFieldRef}
          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                  edge="end"
                  onClick={toggleSecondPopperVisible}
                >
                  <Visibility />
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }}
        />
        <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleSecondPoppertClickAway}>
          <Popper
            open={secondPopperVisible}
            anchorEl={secondTextFieldRef.current}
            placement="bottom-start"
          >
            Content
          </Popper>
        </ClickAwayListener>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

EDIT: Found a temporary solution by wrapping TextField into div and then wrapping tat ClickawayListener. Also prevented propagation on popper itself where needed. This is not ideal, but for my case it worked.

```
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleFirstPopperClickAway}>
<div style={{display: inline-box}>
<TextField>
.....
</TextField>
</div>
</ClickawayListener>
<Popper>
....
</Popper>
```

Comment: Are you simply trying to toggle the visibility of the input content--or do you want to display the content outside the input?

Comment: I want to display custom item picker below input, so user can write information into input as well as pick from a list (popper) below the input.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Wrap the `ClickAwayListener` in a conditional statement:

```
        {firstPopperVisible && (
          <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleFirstPopperClickAway}>
            <Popper open={firstPopperVisible} anchorEl={firstTextFieldRef.current} placement="bottom-start">
              Content
            </Popper>
          </ClickAwayListener>
        )}
       ...
       {secondPopperVisible && (
          <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleSecondPoppertClickAway}>
            <Popper open={secondPopperVisible} anchorEl={secondTextFieldRef.current} placement="bottom-start">
              Content
            </Popper>
          </ClickAwayListener>
        )}
```

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-forked-vw2n5?file=/demo.js:2345-2640)

**PREVIOUS**

I recommend you look at [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) for this. Instead of having multiple elements in the dom, you have one that gets added where needed, as needed.

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node
> that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

Your single Portal component:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Component = ({ content, handleCloseClick }) => {
  return <div onClick={handleCloseClick}>{content}</div>;
};

interface PortalProps {
  isShowing: boolean;
  content: any;
  location: any;
  handleCloseClick: () => void;
}

const Portal = ({ isShowing, content, handleCloseClick, location }: PortalProps) => (isShowing ? ReactDOM.createPortal(<Component handleCloseClick={handleCloseClick} content={content} />, location.current) : null);

export default Portal;
```

Which is then used once in your main component:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import Widget from './Widget';

import './styles.css';

export default function App() {
  const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [content, setContent] = useState<string>();
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const { target } = e;

    buttonRef.current = e.target.parentNode;
    setContent(target.dataset.content);
    setIsShowing(true);
  };

  const handleCloseClick = () => {
    buttonRef.current = null;
    setContent('');
    setIsShowing(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleClick} data-content={`content for one`}>
          One
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleClick} data-content={`content for two`}>
          Two
        </button>
      </div>
      <Widget isShowing={isShowing} location={buttonRef} content={content} handleCloseClick={handleCloseClick} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-bird-bk1fr?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: This works but in my case my both components holding buttons, inputs and contents are independent, so moving content location is not an option. Like date range field where you pick up one date and another date in two separate fields. I don't want to have both poppers open at the same time as they overlap each other. I can't close first one clicking on second one's button as clickaway listener of first one needs mouse event propagated from second events button click. Removing e.stopPropagation triggers both components clickaway listeners and closes second component the same moment it is opened.

Comment: Updated the answer for your scenario, you just need a basic conditional render. I think you can remove `stopPropagation()`

Comment: Thank for update. But still as said before first poppers won't share or receive any state or refs from other poppers. The main issue is independent whether it's single popper or not. Clicking on end adornment acts as onclick and as clickaway event at the same time and stopping propagation of adornment click event will prevent other poppers to be closed in the page. I kind of solved my issue by wrapping TextField with end adornment with clickawaylistener instead of popper and stopped propagation of click events on popper itself.